# UITableView need long press to select a row

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview, long-press

Anyone has ever come into the problem that `UITableView` need long press to trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @iPatel Thank you for the instant answer, it works~

Comment: @keywind: accept iPatel's answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have used any gesture recognizer try to removing it and check if it causing the problem or not ?

**Other wise**

Not sure but The problem might be in the `UITableView` has `delaysContentTouches` turned **ON**. Turn this **OFF** so touches get through to the cells faster.

Answer (score 4):

In my situation I had a UITapGestureRecognizer on my view for hiding my keyboard.

This solved the problem:

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same trouble :

- I used the Tap Gesture recognizer to manage different action in my View Controller
- I wanted a classic tap (short click) to trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but just a long press working by default

My solution to select a cell in Table View by a short tap (press) :

- Select your Tap Gesture recognizer in your Story Board
- Go to the attributes inspector and deselect "Canceled in view"

Comment: This was my problem as well. The flag is called "cancelsTouchesInView" which kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add UILongPressGesture to your cell's view and on fire just call didSelectRowAtIndexPath (better will be to call another method - not standard UITableViewDelegate's method) from your class that adopts UITableViewDelegate.

I will suggest You create own protocol, inherited from UITableViewDelegate, add there method for long press behavior method and enjoy. Something similar to:

```
@protocol LongPressTableViewCellDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didLongTapCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
@end
```

Your delegate in this case would adopt not standard UITableViewDelegate, but this one. Also You have to create own cell (inherited from UITableViewCell) and add there delegate property (id ) that will be used when long press fired.

Also there can be situation that standard didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be fired before your long press will fire, so I suggest you to disable standard selection behavior for table view:

```
_tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Comment: He does not want the long press, he tries to get rid of it