# UITableView row select takes long click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableView to display number of rows. When i click the row it takes long click to perform a action. I have checked this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970757/uitableview-need-long-press-to-select-a-row) it same as my problem. But still it is giving the problem.

//TableView

```
    bookshelfTbaleView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 150)];
    bookshelfTbaleView.delaysContentTouches=NO;
    [bookshelfTbaleView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    bookshelfTbaleView.dataSource=self;
    bookshelfTbaleView.delegate=self;
    bookshelfTbaleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [bookshelfView addSubview:bookshelfTbaleView];
    [scrollview addSubview:popUpBookShelfView];
```

//TableView delegate methods

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [popUpBookShelfView removeFromSuperview];
        bookShelfClick=0;
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return 60;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [bookshelfTbaleView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:18];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    if (tableView==bookshelfTbaleView) {
        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"All Category";
            cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
            cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==1) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Downloaded Category";
            cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
        }

    }
    return cell;
}
```

When the click the row in TableView it takes long click to move to the function

```
tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

This is the value I am getting in table view.

[image]

Can anybody solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: why is the cell always nil?

Comment: before add the text to cell, making it nil

Comment: then you are not really reusing the cell but creating a new one everytime the cellForRow is called.

Comment: i have removed that line of code and checked, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Apple says :

**Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. Use a `UIView` instead of `UIScrollView`.

If you still want to use UITableView in UIScrollView.

Make a custom `UIScrollView` and add this

```
 - (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event  {   

     // If not dragging, send event to next responder
     if (!self.dragging) 
         [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
     else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event]; }
```

Then make a custom `UITableViewCell`

```
 - (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event  {   
     // If not dragging, send event to next responder
     [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event]; }
```

& use this custom Cell.

Comment: if i add the uitableview to uiview then also its giving same problem. Takes long click to go to the fucntion didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: then try second method in answer.

Comment: same problem. may be something wrong in my code it seems. don't know where it is..

Comment: I think you have some UITapGestureRecognizer implemented on any of SuperView of UITableView